# Finding all 5 digit numbers in a column in order to preappend a 1

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to find all five digit numbers in a column in SQL 2008.  They could occur in various forms such as 12345.001 or 12345-001 with text in front of the number or after the number.  Once I identify the number, I would like to preappend a 1 of the 5 digit number

Comment: pre-pend or preappend?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select
    substring(
        col,
        1,
        patindex('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',col))
    +
    '1'
    +
    substring(
        'aa12345aa',
        patindex('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',col)+1,
        1000
    )
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53a43b/16/0

- you can improve my code if you run `patindex()` just once and store the result in a variable.
- 1000 is simply a large enough number.